# Execute ajax requests in a sequential manner which are fired on click of a button

Tags: angularjs, http, q

On click of button, I need to make an ajax request to the back-end to persist the current time and some more details in the database. So, if the user clicks the button multiple times continuously, multiple ajax requests will be fired to the back-end. I want these requests to be executed in a sequential way one after the other and I don't need to keep track of the success/failure of ajax request in the front-end. How to handle these scenarios?

Comment: Well, just send a request at each click of the button. Or do you mean that you don't want to send a request before having received the response of the previous one?

Comment: May be like I want to push all the ajax requests to a queue whenever the user clicks the button. The requests in the queue are to be executed in a synchronous manner. I don't need the response but, I need to wait till the previous request gets successful/failed

Comment: So, by "synchronous", you actually mean "sequential": request 1,  response 1, request 2, response 2, etc. Add each data to send to an array, and use a "finally" promise callback to pop the next data to send from the array and send it.

Comment: Got some clue. But may be at a particular moment, there can be no further requests in the queue. And at some later point of time, if the user clicks the button, I need to add a new request to the array. So, I think I need to check the array continuously, whether there are any new requests in the array.

Comment: No. Whenever the user clicks on the button, either the queue is empty and the previous response has already been received, and you can send the request immediately, or the queue is not empty or the previous response hasn't been received yet, and you just need to add the request to the queue: the previous request handler will take it out as soon as its response is received.

Comment: okay. I will give it a try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use promises to trigger a particular function on the fulfillment of an async request.    https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score -1):

When you call ajax call
just add

> async: false
>    or async: true

in function, the call will synchronise or not